# Facing problem with linking to another page,help needed

Tags: html, django

i been trying to create a Login and a Register page in a django project.i have almost created both the pages except for...i can't link to Login page from Register page and vice versa.I have created a button in the Register page called 'Login' down below the registration form to link it back to Login page if the user already has an account.i have written below code for the button i made:

```
<button>
    <a href="register/">Login</a>
</buttton>
```

and my Register and Login page urls are:

**localhost:8000/register/**

**localhost:8000/login/**

But if i press the button, it takes the user to

**localhost:8000/register/login/**

What i want is to take the user to:

**localhost:8000/login/**

How can i do that?And whats the problem going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write the HTML code like this...

```
<button>
    <a href="/register/">Register</a>
</buttton>
```

OR

```
<button>
    <a href="/login/">Login</a>
</buttton>
```

This will make your URL

```
localhost:8000/register/
```

OR

```
localhost:8000/login/
```

accordingly

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using dynamic urls instead of hardcoded so incase your url/ urls changes in future you will have change it on some places only. Dynamic urls have syntax like: `<a href="{% url 'url_name' %}">Login</a>` 
Where url_name is defined name of your url syntax of url  `path(route, view, name)`

For more information check https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/#example